# Trouble with a web service and Axis2

Tags: java, service, web, apache-axis

Let me say first that I'm a real newbie in Web services, Axis and java IDE.

My job for this week is to modify an existing web service, that was developed under Eclipse by another coleague, some times ago. 
Of course, I cannot access his workspace nor get the settings of his computer.

So, after getting the java classes sources, I have followed various tutorials to set up Eclipse, Tomcat, Axis2 and the web service, on my computer. Everything seems to look fine and I can access to `http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/myservice?wsdl`.

But, when I change one class (eg. add a class member), I don't see any change to the wsdl, even if the code is correctly executed.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right or if I'm clear :-)

I'd like someone to show me some hints to follow.

Thanks !

Comment: are you redeploying the code to the server after making a change?

Comment: don't have a straight answer for you but what you are trying to do is called marshalling and unmarshalling from the object to XML and back.  here is a link you may find useful:  http://wso2.org/library/2068

Comment: I am indeed redeploying the code. When I add some code, say a `system.out.println` line, it's really executed.